# Trigger MouseOver Event Label

Tags: ms-access

Imagine my Access (2016 and above) form has 2 labels, `label1` and `label2`. I want to change the value of `label2` if user moves his mouse inside `label1`. Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Label2.Caption = "Changed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work when typing raw code. How can I get to this event form UI??

Comment: Select Label1, select the Event-tab in the Property Sheet, select On Mouse Move, choose [Event Procedure] in the list. Now Access understands that there is a vba-event on Label1.